# change font type with button in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to do "a custom font type button" in Android Studio with Java. I have some font types(Simonetta_regular, Simonetta_black, Simonetta_black_italic, Simonetta_italic) and I have 1 button and 1 textView. I want the font type of my textview to change when I click the button. I think if I put to a list my font types, I can do it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

there is many way, one of them is this one:

```java
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
Typeface tf= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Tahoma.ttf");
textview.setTypeface(tf);
```

but if u want to set font by default, u can use this:

```java
public class MyButton extends Button {


    public MyButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();

    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();

    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();

    }

    private void init(){

        if (!isInEditMode()){

            Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(),"fonts/Tahoma.ttf");
            this.setTypeface(tf);

        }
    }
}
```